# EJB module from scratch

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb-3.0

I have decided to go into new technology which is EJB (do not ask why, just because). 
Once in a life time I would like to do everything from beginning to end from user terminal, coding in vi and deploying without using maven or any IDE. 
I have also decided to use glassfish.
But I can not find any 'straight' tutorial. Basically each describes steps using netbeans or similar automatic tool. 
Please point me some tutorial with fully described process of creation of ejb from scratch.

Comment: Even in Java EE tutorial, procedure is based on NetBeans IDE. Its good to do it once like creating directories, compiling sources, configuring classpath & libraries, building, deploying etc through the terminal gives better understanding. But its difficult to find it in a single tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a couple of great resources:

http://java.dzone.com/announcements/the-definitive-guide-dependenc

http://java.dzone.com/articles/ejb-31-%E2%80%93-ejb-new-and-improved-

Read Adam Bien's blog, his entire mission is to prove Java and Java EE are the best combination around.

Finally there's a free book  Mastering EJB3.1 as a pdf, its a long but very informative book. Good luck and come back and ask more questions!

Comment: +1 thanks for the Adam Bien tip, his stuff seems to be very to the point/linear... from a Rails background, the amount of info that's is present that I don't know if I can trust, that's too verbose, too old etc is daunting...